# Can one use composition in Rails to create an object that has an interface including the methods of its composite objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm attempting to solve a domain modelling problem in a Rails application via composition.

I have a generic active record `User` class (which has some attributes in the `users` table), but we have a few different flavours of user. Some of these different user types have data stored in different places (for legacy reasons).

For example: `BlueUser` objects have their `email` attribute stored in the `DB.blue_users` table, and `RedUser` objects have their email stored in `DB.red_users`. Note that `blue_users` and `red_users` do not have the same table structure, they just both happen to have an `email`.

My intention is to have the generic `User` class be the only to interact with, and use composition to "create" the `User` objects out of their own properties and methods, in addition to the properties and methods of the composite object (Let's call it the `User_Record` object).

So the `User` class would have its own methods, but then at runtime as the `User` is being instantiated (perhaps via `after_initialize`), a `RedUser` or `BlueUser` object may be instantiated within `User` as the `User_Record` object. Each of the `User_Record` objects/implementations would be Active Record models themselves. I'm then hoping that something can be done so if I ask for the property `User.email`, it can be pulled from the `User_Record` object (without having to call it like `User.record.email`).

I've looked a little bit at `composed_of` in Rails, but am unsure how I might go about unifying the properties / methods of the two objects (so that I wouldn't have to do `User.record.email` elsewhere in the codebase).

I hope my explanation is clear, but if not I'd be happy to take another stab at it.